# Generic Synaptics driver keeps reverting through Windows Update

Tags: windows-8, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I have an [HP ProBook 6550b](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=4173772&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4173845&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4061) laptop and I recently installed Windows 8. After [updating](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&softwareitem=ob-110779-1) the Synaptics driver, I noticed that my OS eventually reverts to a pre-Windows 8 driver without asking me.

**New driver**

[image]

**Old driver**

[image]

Any idea as to why the Synaptics driver would automatically revert to an old pre-Windows 8 version? I don't remember what the default driver was.

**Edit**: I found the culprit. It's coming from the inside: Windows Update. How can I prevent Windows Update from installing the old driver every time I roll back to the 2012 version?

[image]

Comment: Why not try uninstalling the old driver? Then it will use the generic windows driver. After that, install the new synaptic driver and you should be fine.

Comment: Tried that before, but for some reason it keeps coming back.

Comment: Is there a tool that lists all the drivers that are currently installed on my system, including drivers that aren't in use? I might be able to find the old Synaptics driver that way and remove it if it's still there. Another possibility is that Windows 8 is fetching this outdated driver from Windows Update, which can happen even if the driver's not installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. So I ended up reinstalling the newer Touchpad driver (again), then setting Windows Update to only download any new updates. I then did a manual 'check for updates now', and it listed that the Touchpad driver was about to install a new version (which is actually the old version). I then right-clicked on the update and set it to 'hide'.
I haven't tested if this has worked thoroughly, but I still have the updates set to 'Only download', so I can at least check before it installs anything.

Comment: Found the same workaround in the meantime, but forgot to report on it. Thanks for adding this for future reference!

Comment: I wanted to keep automatic install of other important updates, so hiding the update as recommended by Dan's solution worked better for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. Roll back to the driver you want.
2. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> then type `install optional updates` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Click on `Check for updates`.
4. The driver that keeps replacing yours will certainly appear in the `Important updates` section.
5. Untick it, right-click on it and select `Hide update`.

Now Windows should not bother you with it any more.

Comment: Windows 8 kept doing this to me, re-installing an older, signed driver over-top of the newest, unsigned driver. To get to the `Hide Update` option, it's important that you open Windows Update from the classic desktop. Metro does not allow you to hide the updates, but hiding the updates in classic desktop will hide them from Windows Update as well. This solution allows automatic updates of other important updates to continue to install. Here is a [description from Dummies.com](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-hide-windows-updates-that-you-dont-want-to-.html) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do the following:

1. Uninstall all Synaptics drivers
2. Update the driver through device manager.

This will install a fairly recent driver making Windows Update content and not offering any old drivers.